# Migrate android kotlin project to sdk 27

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, kotlin

I want to change targetSdkVersion of my android project from 25 to 27.
The problem is that i used Kotlin and there are some big changes:

1) changed the signature of `View.findViewById()`. Now I need to use `findViewById<View>`

2) `getContext()` of Fragment became not null safety so I need to add !! to all context values in all fragments.

Is there any way to fix it automatically for whole project? This is not a small project and do this fixes manually will take a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

1. There's not an easy way built in to migrate `findViewById` that I know of. I believe I recorded a Vim (IdeaVim) macro to help me when I did it.
2. The nullability of `getContext()` did not change, only the annotation did. In the past `getContext()` could have returned `null`, the compiler just didn't warn you. You should not try to find a way to ignore these errors, or even to add `!!` to each usage. You should instead handle the case where the return value is `null` and do the right thing in your application.